# No search results display when using core search

Tags: search

I have added Drupal the search module block and it displays the search form.

When I type and click on search button, it displays nothing, just a refresh in page only.

What do I need to do to get search results to show up? I could use alternative search modules if that is recommended/necessary.

**Note**: I've already indexed the content. In configuration page, it's showing "*your 100% content has been indexed*".

Comment: You need to run crons so that your data is indexed first. Then you will get some results.

Comment: I've already indexed the content. In configuration page, its showing your 100% content has been indexed.

Comment: When you click on the search button, what's your url looks like? is it something like this example.com/?q=search/node/keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It was just a refresh happens to the page, while clicking the search button.  Anyway, I just added custom search module in drupal and its now working fine :).  Thanks for all :)